# Firebase to GCP BigQuery data export lag

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery

Since Nov 2020 we use BigQuerySQL to process data with from Firebase and make custom reports. We use "Spark" plan with daily data streaming. In july 2021 we noticed, that sometime data streamed with lag. For exaple right now we can process data collected before 13 Aug 2021 and nothing after, but we can see data in firebase dashboard and DataStudio.

Every quotas that we checked says "ok", but there is no tables with events after 12 Aug.

Looks lika a bug, cause we have less that 500k events every day, and it's count doesn't changed dramatically last monhts.

Should we file an issue to GCP or we just misunderstand sometihng?

Comment: Firebase has 18+ products. While you tagged with `firebase-realtime-database`, I don't think there's an integrated BigQuery export for that. Can you confirm exactly what data you're exporting/missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the Spark plan and you have linked to BigQuery as well, then you are under the [limitations of BigQuery Sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox).

In the past similar users reported a sudden stop of the sync, and that's because there is

- a 10GB of active storage limit on BigQuery Sandbox

and they have reached this limit and it was unknown for them.